# How remove color of ccsprite?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I had applied color to a ccsprite. The sprite is initilize with an image of green color. After then i applied red color to it. Now how to remove the red color and bring it back to original image color?

Suppose this is the original image
[image]

Now when i apply red color to it, it is colored as red. My question is **how to remove this color which i recently applied?**

The code i use is

```
CCSprite *ballSprite=[[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"ball.png"];
ballSprite.color=ccRED;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
allSprite.color = ccWHITE;
```